# Is there a word to describe the portion of one's total funds that may be spent as opposed to the portion which must be held on to?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, predicate-adjectives

I cannot think what else I might add...

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: I think that is usually referred to as _disposable income_.

Comment: My **budget** is what I can afford to spend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **Disposable** income is net income. It's the amount left over after taxes.
> - **Discretionary** income is the amount of net income remaining after all basic necessities are covered.
> - Economists monitor these numbers at a macro level to see how consumers are saving, spending, and borrowing.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/disposableincome.asp

> **Available Asset**
>
> 1. An asset that is not being used as collateral on a loan and may therefore be sold or donated. In other words, an available asset is any asset with no restrictions on its use.
> 2. See: **Liquid asset**.

https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/available+asset

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of disposable income but just couldn't come up with the word.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this money as ***discretionary income***, which is the portion of your salary that doesn't go toward necessary bills such as taxes, housing, food, etc. You may also hear the term ***disposable income*** used synonymously, but apparently that refers to any income left after taxes, but still includes money that will be spent on necessary bills and cannot be spent "freely".

More general terms for money that isn't earmarked for anything in particular would be ***spending money*** or ***pocket money***. These usually refer to not-very-large sums of money that can be spent as one pleases.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of disposable income but just couldn't come up with the word.